# Mathematical game wondering

Tags: math

Imagine an arm that is 50 px long.
It is placed at 100,100.
The rotation center is at 100, 100.
The arm rotates all the time.
On the arm there is a hook that travels back and forth the full distance of the arm.

My variables:

```
X = 100;
Y = 100;
RotationAngel = 120; // Loops up to 360.
HookDistanceFromCenter = 25; // Goes 0 -> 50 -> 0 by a loop.
```

How do I get the position (x,y) of the hook?

Comment: Haha. No!
Building a game with a hook! (i am 34, but bad at math...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your specific data:

```
x = 100 - HookDistanceFromCenter * cos(180 - RotationAngle)
y = 100 + HookDistanceFromCenter * sin(180 - RotationAngle)
```

but it changes depending on which quadrant you are in. This is basic trigonometry. You should be able to use the info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle except that the radius of your circle is `HookDistanceFromCenter` and you have to add your rotation center coordinates to the result to get the actual `(x,y)`.

Comment: By "which quadrant" you mean RotationAngle < 90 || RotationAngle < 180 || RotationAngle < 270 || RotationAngle < 360 ?

Comment: yes, although to be pedantic I mean 0 < RA <= 90, 90 < RA <= 180, 180 < RA <= 270, 270 < RA < 360

Comment: And in which way does the result of this change your code example?

Comment: the x,y distance from the rotation center changes sign as it goes from quadrant to quadrant; in 1 they are both positive, in 2 x is negative, in 3 both are negative, and in 4 only y is negative. Does that make sense?

Comment: So in case 2: the result might be x=-60 but then i change it to x=60?

Comment: No; you should really read that unit circle article on wikipedia. For example, at 120 degrees, your x diff is `0.5 * HookDistanceFromCenter` but in the negative direction, so you subtract it from your rotation center coordinates.